# How to give relative path in DNN of MathJax

Tags: dotnetnuke, mathjax

I have installed DNN (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DNN) and MathJax(C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DNN\MathJax) locally on my computer. 
I am adding my custom made html  page (which uses MathJax) in default DNN skin.

right now ... for rendering MathML i am using the following CDN link

but i want to use Math Jax , which is locally installed at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DNN\MathJax). I have tried to give relative path but nothing works.

The issue, which i have understand is that  DNN is CMS and it saved the pages dynamically so how can i give the relative path of MathJax in my custom made html file ?

Or

Is it possible to host MathJax in DNN so that i can provide that url in the script tag?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since I guess MathJax is ultimately a javascript, you can simply reference in your script like `<script src="/MathJax/..."` and it will work properly. What exact problems are you having with this?

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that the virtual Urls in DNN will cause different relative Urls when trying to map.

The easiest solution is to use an absolute path to your library.

However, if you want a relative path (and you're using the text/html module - which I'm assuming, because you didn't specify) then you can use the text substitution available in that module.

Basically, you can use the portal home directory and construct a relative path from there (using ../..)

See this article explaining text substitution in the html module:
http://www.datasprings.com/resources/articles-information/dnn-text-html-token-replacement-options

Alternatively, if you're writing your own module, then you can use the properties of the framework which will give you the root path of the website.